# What is wrong with my answer about Etruscan

Tags: discussion

On this answer, I got one upvote and two downvotes: https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/18204/8533

Why the downvotes?

Comment: If I had to hazard a guess it may be because some people didn't like your source and would prefer something more "official" than Reddit.

Comment: I see that you edited the answer. Did you receive the votes before you edited it? If so, it might be because you had only provided a link without explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I downvoted because it's phrased as a new question, not as an answer. "What do you think?" generally isn't a good answer (especially to your own question).